# How can i implement an NPM compatible package registry from scratch?

Tags: npm, package, registry

I would like to implement my own NPM compatible package registry, like 'github packages'.

Where can i find documentation of how this is done?

---

For example;

```
npm login --registry https://myregistry.com
```

and

```
npm install
```

will both send post/get request to the registry. Where can i find documentation on how to implement those endpoints? Is this public information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the response from the npm registry is located at github:

https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/responses/package-metadata.md#dist

Comment: Please avoid documentation-request questions. Also, link-only answers aren't really valid answers. If anything, this should be a comment under the question.

Comment: "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. You can edit the question or post a new one." <--- where does it specify documentation?

Comment: It's a recommendation for any offsite resource. Documentation is included with "and more". Point is, you're answering with a link to an offsite resource. The question asks "*Where can i find documentation on how to implement those endpoints?*" - and that is expressly off-topic.